# Plotting a plot with an additional y axis on the right and an additional x axis on the top, linked to the bottom one

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to make a figure that has two plots, that share the same x axis on the bottom, one is linked to the left y axis, the other to the right y axis, and also have the top x-axis, which is a function of the bottom x-axis (current divided by area). Basically what I would like to have in the end is something like the attached figure on the left.
So far I can only make the plots with the left and right y axis, but I cannot find the right way to also include the top x-axis. I have run out of ideas, and I would like to request you help and suggestions on how to deal with this.
This is what I have tried so far:

```
# Open and Plot Data

fname = folder + r'/' +f
#print(fname)
vect = np.loadtxt(fname, delimiter=' ')

current = vect[:,0]
voltage = vect[:,1]
power = vect[:,2]
current_density=current/area1/1000 #in kA/cm^2



fig,ax1=plt.subplots()
ax1.plot(current,voltage)
#l = ax2.plot(current_density,voltage)
#l.set_visible(False)



#ax1.grid(True) #add a grid to the LIV

#ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax2= ax1.twinx()
#ax2=ax1.twiny()
ax2.plot(current, power)
```

[image: Basically, what I need is on the right]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right axis would be a **twin** axes, using the same x axis, but a different y axis as the original one.
The top axis would be a **secondary axis**, being linked to the original x axis by a functional dependence.

In total:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax_right = ax.twinx()

area = 0.226
density = lambda current: current / area / 1000
current = lambda density: density * area * 1000
ax_top  = ax.secondary_xaxis("top", functions=(density, current))

ax.plot([0, 250, 565], [0,8,12], label="Voltage")
ax_right.plot([0, 300, 565], [0, 0.3, 40], label="Power", color="C3")

ax.set_xlabel("Current [mA]")
ax.set_ylabel("Voltage [V]")
ax_right.set_ylabel("Power [mW]", color="C3")
ax_top.set_xlabel("Density [kA/cm${}^2$]", color="C1")

ax_right.tick_params(axis="y", color="C3", labelcolor="C3")
ax_right.spines["right"].set_color("C3")

ax_top.set_color("C1")
ax.spines["top"].set_color("C1")
ax_right.spines["top"].set_color("C1")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This looks like the right way to do it. However, in my case I am getting the following error: AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'secondary_xaxis'. The version of my matplotlib is 3.0.2.

Comment: Yes, it'll require matplotlib 3.1 or higher.

Comment: That was it. Thank you very much for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can do something like this:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2)

# set up clones
axes_cp = []
for i in range(2):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1,2,i+1)
    ax.set_alpha(0)
    ax.set_facecolor('none')
    ax.xaxis.tick_top()
    ax.yaxis.tick_right()

    axes_cp.append(ax)

# plot
axes[0].plot([0,1], [0,1])
axes_cp[0].plot([0,100], [100,0], color='r')

x = np.linspace(0,1,100)
axes[1].plot(x, x**2)
axes_cp[1].plot(x, np.sqrt(x), color='r')

fig.tight_layout()
```

Output:

[image]